# generalisation of Knonecker matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

In the Kronecker matrix product  $C = A\otimes B$ 
we have that $C(i,j)=A(i,j)*B$
where the elements $A(i,j)$ are just numeric scalar values.

What if the $A(i,j)$ are matrix operators which act on $B$?  Is there a name for that formalism or matrix product?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this operation has a name. In fact, this operation can be conveniently with the help of the Kronecker product, e.g. for the $2\times 2$ case the product you give is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} B & A_{12}B\\ A_{21}B & A_{22}B
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is the same as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12}\\ A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
B & 0\\ 0 & B
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11} & A_{12}\\ A_{21} & A_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
(I_2\otimes B)
$$
(where $I_2$ denotes the $2\times 2$ identity). 
The $n\times m$ case is similar, replace the $2$ by $m$.